# Delete and Re-Add Disqus Site

Tags: accounts

I have a site that uses Disqus, and I've messed up the comments/discussions data beyond the point of recovery. I'd like to simply delete the site and start fresh. I know that all of my comments/discussions will be deleted, but I've been unable to find whether you can add a site that was previously deleted (that is, same name and shortname). Anyone know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I went ahead and did it. The answer is yes. Once the site is gone, it's totally gone. You can subsequently add a new site with the same shortname.

Comment: Glad you resolved this. Please be sure to [mark your answer as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) when you are able.

Comment: haha if I remember about this two days from now, I will.